# CakePHP and Rails: slowly port old php functionality to new rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cakephp

I am a rails developer working on a cakephp site. The more work they send me, the more php code I write and thus the more dependence on php we introduce. What I want is to stop writing new features in php and start writing them in rails. Our resources are limited and the existing php site is huge so a full port from cake to rails is not possible.

Is there some way to write new features in a rails app while maintaining and allowing access to all the functionality of the old php (and vice-versa)?

It seems I would need a route aware app to traffic requests to either php or rails, but then we run into the issue of, for example, existing user functionality written in php not being available to the rails app and vice-versa.

What about something to translate ruby into php? That way I could start writing my model stuff in ruby/rails rather than php.

I feel like my question is muddled by the fact I do not know how to ask the questions I want to answer, so hopefully this is understood.

As always, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach that you may find useful is to leverage the power of your web-server to properly re-write and delegate requests to two different systems. If you can design your new Rails application to use the same database records as the old one, with models mapping to the old tables directly, and ensuring that sessions established by one are valid in the other, you have a lot of latitude in how you go about doing this.

Apache has a very full-featured URL rewriting and proxying system that can be configured to direct "legacy" parts of your site to an existing set of PHP scripts while directing all other traffic to the new Rails application. You will need to be careful to ensure the design of both applications are nearly identical or it may seem strange to users.

Another approach that helps ensure a consistent appearance is to strip out a lot of the theme from your PHP application. By creating very bare-bones pages that only expose the required functionality on each page, Rails can fetch these by passing through any relevant session authentication information and re-frame them in the right layout.

This way you can preserve existing functionality and have it embedded inside your new application. You can use something as simple as `open-uri` or the `curb` gem to handle this HTTP-level delegation.

You would end up with controllers that look like this:

```
class PaymentController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @content = fetch_legacy_url('/payments/index.php'))
  end
end
```

The `fetch_legacy_url` method would create an HTTP fetch request that includes the required headers, cookies, and so forth, and return the response body. Your view then ends up looking something like this:

```
<%= @content =>
```

From there you can shunt parts of the PHP layout over to the Rails app piece by piece. For instance, ripping out large chunks of static HTML and putting them in the Rails template would reduce the amount of actual PHP code you have to port.

It's a bit messy to maintain two applications in parallel, but as you point out the alternative is to keep accumulating technical debt and making the inevitable re-write that much more significant an undertaking.

The first step would be to experiment and see if you can create a Rails environment that uses your existing data, or at least the data relevant to the new functionality you intend to build out.

Comment: Thanks @tadman. it definitely sounds like there are some big landmines to avoid and maintenance issues that could spring up very quickly, especially when working on an agile team of several developers. However, it makes sense and sounds like a huge step in the right direction, so thank you for your in depth response. It is appreciated.